# The sign of $0$ is both positive and negative or neither positive nor negative?

Tags: number-theory

I was thinking about the likelihood ratio test and it seemed to me that *both positive and negative* argument should be preferred instead of *neither positive nor negative* when we define the sign of zero.

Let me explain what led me to this conclusion. Assume we have apples and pears in a box and they are transmitted from a transmitter to the receiver one by one via an unfriendly transporter. As a results an apple might be undergone a heavy damage during the travel and might seem like a pear or vice verse, i.e., a pear might look like an apple.

our aim at the receiver side is to decide if an apple was sent or a pear. To do this we have a deformaton profile both for an apple and a pear. Those are the probability density functions $f_{apple}$ and $f_{pear}$. Whenever we receive a deformed fruit, say $y$, which is known to us previously that it is either apple or pear, we give a decision based on our models, namely $f_{apple}$ or $f_{pear}$ as follows

$$l(y)=\frac{f_{apple}(y)}{f_{pear}(y)} \stackrel{\mbox{apple}}{\underset{\mbox{pear}}{\gtrless}} 1$$

In words, if the probability that $y$ comes from our model $f_{apple}$ is greater than the probability that it comes from $f_{pear}$, we decide for $f_{apple}$, else for $f_{pear}$.

When we take the $\log$ of both sides we get

$$\log l(y)=\log \frac{f_{apple}(y)}{f_{pear}(y)} \stackrel{\mbox{apple}}{\underset{\mbox{pear}}{\gtrless}} 0$$

Now we are interested in what happens if $f_{apple}(y)=f_{pear}(y)$? definitely we can not produce any useful decision. But we can say fifty-fifty, namely $50\%$ it is apple or pear.

In this problem decision for an apple means a sign of positive and a decision of a pear means a sign of negative. When we are at point $0$, we see that the decision involves $50\%$ apple and $50\%$ pear, as a result one would not expect that $y$ is a *banana*. It is either an apple or a pear. As a result at point $0$ we have both an apple and a pear with a $0.5$ probability. This suggests that $0$ is both positive and negative which is also in agreement with the use of *signed zeros*..

> My question is: is there any example which could indicate that the pair *neither-nor* is more suitable for zero? or are there more examples supporting my ideas above?

Thanks for reading this post and for any nice comment, even for not nice ones.

Comment: If $0$ is both positive and negative, how do you define $\operatorname{sgn}0$?

Comment: @tohecz I cannot define but $0$ can still be both positive and negative. I mean simultaneously positive and negative, not either of them at a time.

Comment: I mean examples like this: "The derivative of $x\mapsto |x|$ is $+1$ for positive $x$ and $-1$ for negative $x$.

Comment: @tohecz i see your point. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 4):

Zero has no "sign". We have the *positive numbers*, $x>0$, the *negative numbers*, $x<0$, and the zero. That is, zero is a breaking point, so to speak.

To dwell into more details, suppose you have a field $F$, that is, a set $F$ with operations of addition and multiplication, a $1$ and a $0$, $1\neq 0$, and suppose moreover we have a subset $P$ of that field, called the "positive numbers" (or positive cone) with the following properties:

$(1)$ Whenever $x,y\in P$, $xy,x+y\in P$,

$(2)$ For any $x\in F$; either $x\in P$, or $-x\in P$,  and

$(3)$ $0\notin P$.

We ask, moreover, that $F=\{0\}\sqcup P\sqcup P'$ where $P'=-P=\{-x;x\in P\}$.

Then we can define an order in $F$ by stating $x>y$ iff $x-y\in P$. We thus say $x>0$ when $x\in P$, that is $x$ is "positive". Since $0$ is not in $P$ (the positive numbers) and neither is in $P'$ (the negative numbers), we cannot speak of $0$ "having a sign."

Comment: so you think neither-nor is more suitable?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören I haven't read your question when I answered this, merely the title. I would say zero is nor positive nor negative, i.e. it has no "sign."

Answer (score 1):

In some situations, we might use the number 0 as a shorthand for a very small quantity $x$ appoaching to zero. In this case, the size of $x$ may not be so relevant, but its sign may be. For example, $1/x \approx +\infty$ for $x$ small positive and $1/x \approx -\infty$ for $x$ small negative.

In these cases, it's helpful to distinguish between positive zero and negative zero. (IEEE floating-point math makes this distinction). We might say $1/+0 = \infty$ and $1/-0 = -\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

At one time, the Bourbaki school considered 0 as both positive and negative but this is not a common position today.  Today, it is more common to regard it as neither positive nor negative.

I found an interesting footnote in this book: [The Number System by H.A.Thurston](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=I1PiN8gnUjcC&pg=PA15&lpg=PA15&dq=bourbaki%20zero%20positive%20negative&source=bl&ots=b9xzlvKpMc&sig=N2UX1D6DDu5wvGFU1jDL0Xi2qyM&hl=en&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiUlsfdiZrTAhUhIpoKHcRSApUQ6AEIKjAD#v=onepage&q=bourbaki%20zero%20positive%20negative&f=false) at the bottom of page 15.